# Is there a Python function that checks if any list element is of a specific data type?

Tags: python

For example: I have a list called `container`. In it are some elements and I want to check if eg. any of them are complex.

```
container = [1, 0.5, "text", 1j]    
if isinstance(container[?], complex):
    print("This list has complex elements")
```

In this example, I could've written `container[-1]`, but is there an universal method?
I *could* use a for loop, but I'm wondering if there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to apply something to entire container, e.g.

```
any(isinstance(element, complex) for element in container)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension along with python's `any()` function:

```
any([isinstance(x, complex) for x in container])
```

This would return `True` if the list has complex numbers.

Comment: This is practically the same solution as [lejlot's answer](/a/70229110/4518341), though it'll be slower if `container` is very large, since `any` can't short-circuit a list [like it can a generator](/a/17246413/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

With pure python I think you would have to explicitly iterate over the list.  It can be done with a simple list comprehension:

```py
if any([isinstance(c, complex) for c in container]):
    print("List has complex elements")
```

Comment: This is practically the same solution as [lejlot's answer](/a/70229110/4518341), though it'll be slower if `container` is very large, since `any` can't short-circuit a list [like it can a generator](/a/17246413/4518341).

Comment: Thanks @wjandrea, I never think of using generators for some reason, that answer is definitely better.